# TFS Check In The request was aborted: The request was canceled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, rotativa

I'm trying to check in with my application but it is giving the following error:

...\Rotativa\wkhtmltopdf.exe: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Is there a virus scanner running on the TFS Application Tier?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue and found this

Through the client side I tried the following solution which solve my problem with

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="VersionControl.UploadChunkSize" value="1048576" />
</appSettings>
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably 7 months too late but...

Saw the same error trying to check into TFS from a Visual Studio instance running in a virtual machine on my local computer. Turns out that I had my network set to "VMnet8 (NAT)" so the virtual machine was sharing an IP address with the host. Changing the network to bridged solved my issue.

Hope this helps!